# Dynamic return type in a function

Tags: go

I have a function that is called from an other package. This function parses a text string received in the argument and returns a splice of structs. These structs are, in my case, 7 and all differ in some fields. I'm trying to return an `interface{}` type but I'd like to be able to assert the type on the receiving end as I need to do other operations on that struct.

So far I've got to this point (the function are meant to be in different packages):

```golang
func Process(input string) interface{} {
 // ...
 switch model {
 case 1:
  output := model1.Parse(input) // this function returns a []MOD1 type
  return output
 }
 case 2:
  output := model2.Parse(input) // this function returns a []MOD2 type
  return output
 }
 // other cases with other models
}

func main() {
 // ...
 output := package.Process(input) // now output is of type interface{}
 
 // I need the splice because I'll publish each element to a PubSub topic
 for _, doc := range output {
    obj, err := json.Marshal(doc)
    if err != nil {
        // err handling
    }

    err = publisher.Push(obj)
    if err != nil {
        // err handling
    }
 }
}
```

Now in `main()` I'd like `output` to be of type `[]MOD1`, `[]MOD2`, ..., or `[]MOD7`.

I've tried the to use the `switch t := output.(type)` but `t` exists only in the scope of the switch case and it doesn't really solve my problem.

```golang
func main() {
 output := package.Process(input)
 switch t := output.(type) {
 case []MOD1:
    output = t // output is still of type interface{}
 case []MOD2:
    output = t
 }
}
```

I need this because in the `main` func I have to do other operations on that structure and eventually Marshall it into a JSON. I've thought of marshalling the structs in the `Process` func and return the `[]byte` but then I'd need to unmarshall in `main` without knowing the struct's type.

Comment: There isn't really much to show, I can't use `t := output.(type)` without the switch case, or at least this is the error Go throws out.. I'll add the snippet I used anyway

Comment: what's the point of `output = t` in the type switch? shouldn't the switch be used to select a certain operation depending on the type of `output`?

Comment: There is a lot of code in main. I need the spliced structs because I have to publish each separate element to a PubSub topic (GCloud), but the actual message to publish would be the jsonified struct of the single element. I'll try to add something to the code.

Comment: MrFuppes yes I know it is wrong, I didn't understand the mechanism when I read it on an other question.

Comment: @cartinez If the only thing `main` does with an individual slice element is marshal the element to JSON, then change the return type of `Process` to `[]interface{}`.   Add code to each type switch case in `Process` to convert from slice of concrete type to `[]interface{}`.

Comment: @CeriseLimón right, I was actually coming up with this as I was editing the question with the code. I think this would be the better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Process1` to return a `[]interface{}`:

```
func Process(input string) []interface{} {
 // ...
 switch model {
 case 1:
  output := model1.Parse(input)
  result := make([]interface{}, len(output))
  for i := range result {
     result[i] = output[i]
  }
  return result
 }
 case 2:
 // other cases with other models
}
```

Work with the `[]interface{}` in main:

```
 output := package.Process(input)
 for _, doc := range output {
    obj, err := json.Marshal(doc)
    if err != nil {
        // err handling
    }

    err = publisher.Push(obj)
    if err != nil {
        // err handling
    }
 }
```